# wamp server 2.0 loses a record after i log out

Tags: php, mysql, forms, wampserver

I have a site which has a sign up option to create accounts. It lets me create an account after which i log in into it. But after i log out and try to login again it tells me invalid username and password. It seems the Wamp database is losing the record/account I create after log out. It is also happening with my other sites. I am using Wamp server 2.0 with Macromedia Dw 8.0. Also tried Xampp but still same problem. The site is made of mostly Php and Mysql coding.
Please help.

```
<?php
$server="localhost";
  $user="root";
$pwd="";
$db="GlobalStyling";
$conn=mysql_connect($server,$user,$pwd) or die(mysql_error());
$sql="drop DATABASE $db";
mysql_query($sql);
$sql="CREATE DATABASE GlobalStyling";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die ("unable to create database");
mysql_select_db($db) or die(mysql_error()."unable to select database");
 $query1="Create table members
           (
  `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `middlename` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `contact_no` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `age` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`member_id`)
)";
      $query_run=mysql_query($query1);

$query2="Create table note
    (
  `note_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `message` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`note_id`)
)";
      $query_run=mysql_query($query2);

$query3="Create table schedule
 (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `service_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)";
       $query_run=mysql_query($query3);   


$query4="Create table service
 (
  `service_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `service_offer` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`service_id`)
)";
      $query_run=mysql_query($query4);   
$query5="Create table users
  (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
)";
  $query_run=mysql_query($query5);   
?>
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<!-- -->
      <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse"  
    data-target=".nav-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="active" ><a rel="tooltip"  
data-placement="bottom" title="Home" id="home" href="index.php" 
    class=""><i 
    class="icon-home icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Home</a></li>
                    <li><a rel="tooltip"  data-placement="bottom" 
    title="Services" id="services" href="services.php" class=""><i 
    class="icon-list icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Services</a></li>
                    <li><a rel="tooltip"  data-placement="bottom" 
    title="About Us" id="aboutus" href="about.php" class=""><i 
    class="icon-info 
    icon-large"></i>&nbsp;About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a rel="tooltip"  data-placement="bottom" 
   title="Contact Us" id="contactus" href="contact_us.php" class=""><i   
    class="icon-phone icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Contact US</a></li>

                    </ul>
                         <form class="navbar-search pull-right">
                         <input type="text" class="search-query"        
    placeholder="Search">
                         </form>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<!-- -->
<?php include('dbcon.php'); ?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="margin-top">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
            <?php include('banner.php'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="span12">
            <div class="caption_index">we provide                       
the                          quality         dental service</div>
            </div>      
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="span12">
                <?php include('thumbnail.php'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="span12">
            <?php include('content1.php'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="span12">
            <?php include('content2.php'); ?>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php include('footer.php') ?>`*
```

Comment: please post your code logout() function..

Comment: my logout.php page has this code which works with the logout button

<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header('location:index.php');
?>

Comment: there is something wrong in your code, since wamp or xampp servers will not delete any records automatic until you do something, need more information about your function register(), login(), logout() and how do you make queries to database.

Comment: Please bear with me as am a beginner with this

Comment: I have a page called index.php which makes the connection and creates the database and the tables
code below:

Comment: <?php
$server="localhost";
$user="root";
$pwd="";
$db="GlobalStyling";
$conn=mysql_connect($server,$user,$pwd) or die(mysql_error());
$sql="drop DATABASE $db";
mysql_query($sql);
$sql="CREATE DATABASE GlobalStyling";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die ("unable to create database");
mysql_select_db($db) or die(mysql_error()."unable to select database");


$query2="Create table note
  (
  `note_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `message` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`note_id`)

)";
   $query_run=mysql_query($query2);
   

etc etc ...................

Comment: naahh, I see `$sql="drop DATABASE $db"; ` this is what caused your table gone. Please edit and post your full index.php code to your question. Its hard to read in comment area.

Comment: actually not the table but the records in it get deleted automatically let me edit my question for full index.php

Comment: The code you show DROP's the database and re-creates it on **each execution** How do you expect to preserve data if you remove it each time you execute this code.

Comment: but when i remove that line it does not load my site and says unable to create database

Comment: please show me a modified code i can try

Comment: i understand that the drop thing is for creating a new database when a user loads the site so that a database with a similar name but not relating to the site gets deleted
my logout was redirecting back to the index page which meant that the database was being recreated and hence the deletion of records
i managed to overcome the problem by redirecting my logout to the login now instead of index so that that code would be avoided but the login page is somehow like a homepage and not fully (index page was fully like homepage but now i am forced to avoid it)
therefor problem resolved in bad way

Comment: You can create procedure to check a database exists or not to avoid recreating database, so you can still user your index.php. I will post example code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an examples code to check database exists or not, please note am using `mysqli` instead `mysql`because [this reason](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pwd = "";
$db = "GlobalStyling";
$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pwd);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$dbExists = mysqli_select_db($conn, $db);
// Checking if Database not Exists
if(!$dbExists) {
    // Create Database
    $sql = "CREATE DATABASE $db";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    // Create Table
    mysqli_select_db($conn, $db);
    $query1 = "Create table members
      (
      `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `firstname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `lastname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `middlename` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `contact_no` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `age` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `gender` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`member_id`)
      )";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);

    $query2 = "Create table note
      (
      `note_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `date` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `message` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`note_id`)
      )";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);

    $query3 = "Create table schedule
      (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `date` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `service_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `Number` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `status` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
      )";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $query3);

    $query4 = "Create table service
      (
      `service_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `service_offer` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `price` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`service_id`)
      )";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $query4);

    $query5 = "Create table users
      (
      `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
      )";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $query5);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

The example code isn't the most beautiful code you'll ever see.

Comment: ok i was able to use index page once again without losing records
and fortunately the mysqli code worked with my wamp 2.0
thank you very much to all !!!